# pop3 mail client(openpop.net) failed to get a mail which has been scanned by SurfControl plc

Tags: c#, .net, client, pop3

I am using pop3 client(openpop.net) to get a mail from a pop3 server. It works fine for all mails till now. But now it failed to get a mail using the **GetMessage(index)** method. The message object obtained from the above method is **null** for the particular mail.

I checked the mail manually and when i opened it i found the following message inside it:

**This message has been scanned for malware by SurfControl plc. www.surfcontrol.com**

The c#.net code is as follows:

```
using (Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client())
{
    client.Connect(HostName, Port, UseSsl);
    client.Authenticate(UserName, Password);

    int MessageCount = client.GetMessageCount();

    MessageHeader h= client.GetMessageHeaders(MessageCount);

    List<int> deleteIndexes = new List<int>();

    #region Process all mails

    for (int index = 1; index <= MessageCount; index++)
    {
        try
        {
            #region Process the downloaded mail

            Message message;

            try
            {
                message = client.GetMessage(index);
            }
            catch
            {

            }

            MessageHeader Headers = message.Headers;

            RfcMailAddress FromMail = Headers.From;
            string Subject = Headers.Subject;
            string From = FromMail.Address;
            string ReceivedDate = Headers.DateSent.ToLocalTime().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Why did i am not able to get this mail using the mentioned function of pop3 client? Any one please help me to sort out this issue..

### Stack Trace:

> at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options,
>   NumberBuffer&                  number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean
>   parseDecimal)    at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles
>   style, NumberFormatInfo info)    at System.Int32.Parse(String s,
>   IFormatProvider provider)    at
>   OpenPop.Mime.Header.HeaderFieldParser.ParseContentDisposition(String
>   headerValue)    at
>   OpenPop.Mime.Header.MessageHeader.ParseHeader(String headerName,
>   String headerValue)    at
>   OpenPop.Mime.Header.MessageHeader.ParseHeaders(NameValueCollection
>   headers)    at
>   OpenPop.Mime.Header.MessageHeader..ctor(NameValueCollection headers)
>   at OpenPop.Mime.Header.HeaderExtractor.ExtractHeadersAndBody(Byte[]
>   fullRawMessage, MessageHeader& headers, Byte[]& body)    at
>   OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart.GetMessagePart(Byte[] rawMessageContent)
>   at OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart.ParseMultiPartBody(Byte[] rawBody)    at
>   OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart.ParseBody(Byte[] rawBody)    at
>   OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart..ctor(Byte[] rawBody, MessageHeader headers) 
>   at OpenPop.Mime.Message..ctor(Byte[] rawMessageContent, Boolean
>   parseBody)    at OpenPop.Mime.Message..ctor(Byte[] rawMessageContent) 
>   at OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client.GetMessage(Int32 messageNumber)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenPop.NET states that the best way to get support is to contact them on their mailing list:
hpop-users@lists.sourceforge.net

Are any exceptions being thrown by `GetMessage(index)`? It is not be possible for `GetMessage(index)` to return a null reference - but if it throws an exception your catch clause will do nothing and you will continue like nothing happened, and the `message` variable will not be set. Could you tell us if any exceptions are raised and give us the stack-trace if so?

Also, if you have not removed any code before posting this question, your code looks like a mess. Why are you fetching headers for the last message in the mailbox with the line:

```
MessageHeader h= client.GetMessageHeaders(MessageCount);
```

It does not seem that you are using it.

Also, it looks like in your for-loop, that you are fetching an email, only to look at the headers - then you should use the `GetMessageHeaders(index)` method to save bandwidth.

Comment: I used that code to check the header of the failed message as my message object is null.Also this is only a portion of code for some other purpose, i just added the problematic section.. Yes, i do get an exception which is as follows:FormatException was caught- "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: Then it seems there is a bug in the OpenPop.NET code. I am one of the authors, and I think you should contact us at the mailing list along with a stacktrace and the full email it fails parsing. Then I will have a look at tit. You can of course also post it here.

Comment: It is actually a private mail from my client and as a result i cannot reveal the mail. I've updated the question with my stack trace. Also i would like to inform that the "SurfControl plc" is at the client side and i do not have any control. You can download the security tool from  "www.surfcontrol.com" for your testing purpose.

Comment: We have worked on the issue over email on the project mailing list. The process showed there was a bug in parsing Content-Disposition headers, where a size parameter value was in quotes, which was not expected. The bug has been fixed and committed.

Comment: I've downloaded the updated source from "http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=svn&group_id=92166" and it worked fine.. Thanks once again for your effort....

Comment: Does the older version of OpenPOP have problem with parsing **Content-Disposition: attachment**? It seems **Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xml"** works fine.

Comment: @Babak: The problem reported by Harun was about the filesize property. As I recall, the filename property does not have this problem.